# Enters the method but does not display anything

Tags: methods, call, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to call a method to ViewController class form AppDelegate, it enter to the method but the problem is that is not displaying anything , I was looking for, but I can´t find the answer. Some one could help me? thanks

this is the code :

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    if (mainDelegate.isflagON=TRUE)
    {

        ViewController *vc=[ViewController new];
        [vc pause];

    }

}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *mainDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (mainDelegate.isflagON==false)
    {
        mainDelegate.isflagON=true;
        CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
        // Add this line

        GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:viewSize];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        self.scene = scene;

        // Configure the view.
        skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];

    }else
    {
        [self doPause];
    }
}

-(void) imprime
{
    [self doPause];

}

- (void)doPause {

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [backImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dialogBox.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:backImageView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backImageView];

    //set the position of the button

    buttonContinuar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [buttonContinuar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dialogButton.png"]
                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonContinuar.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 50.0f, 120, 35);
    [buttonContinuar addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonWasClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonContinuar setTitle:@"Continuar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:buttonContinuar];

    buttonMapa = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button setTitle:@"Continuar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [buttonMapa setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dialogButton.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMapa.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 85.0f, 120, 35);
    [buttonMapa addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMapaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonMapa setTitle:@"Mapa" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:buttonMapa];

    buttonMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //[button setTitle:@"Continuar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [buttonMenu setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dialogButton.png"]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMenu.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 120.0f, 120, 35);
    [buttonMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonMenuClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonMenu setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:buttonMenu];

}
```

Comment: Your code is a massive formatting mess so I haven't got very far into it, but I can tell you that the first line contains an error. You're using the assignment operator, when you should be using the equality operator. In other words `if (mainDelegate.isflagON = TRUE)` should be `if (mainDelegate.isflagON == TRUE)`

Comment: Also, in Objective-C you should use YES/NO rather than TRUE/FALSE

Comment: And in the second line you shouldn't do "ViewController *vc=[ViewController new]" but do [[ViewController alloc] init].

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    if (mainDelegate.isflagON=TRUE)
    {

        ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
        [vc pause];

    }

}
```